# Web Scraping: I am getting the desired result but get_text is providing an error when it reads an empty line. Any ideas?

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States"

page = requests.get(url)

#print(page.status_code)

#print(page.content)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#print(soup.prettify())


tb = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')

"""for link in tb.find_all('b'):
    name = link.find('a')
    print(name)"""

for link in tb.find_all('b'):
    name = link.find('a')
    print(name.get_text('title'))
```

[image: Picture of code and result]

I believe it is reading the table and then when it gets to an empty line I am getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

find method returns `None` if the requested tag is not found, so you have to check for that:

```
for link in tb.find_all('b'):
    name = link.find('a')
    if name is not None:
        print(name.get_text())
```

Also `.get_text` method just strips every tag and returns the text inside, so the argument you pass might not do what you expect it to do. Soup just treats it as a separator. Here's this method's signature:

```
def get_text(self, separator="", strip=False,
             types=default):
```

Documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Comment: The find method worked perfectly! Thank you so much.